# Blog facilities in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, blogs

I'm developing a quite simple site at least for now.
What I want is to make it possible for administrator to create posts (articles). And further to form a blog in a subdomain.

I didn't find a tutorial on blog development using ASP.NET MVC 3. Can you provide any useful tutorial/post/book.

Thanks!

Comment: You're kidding, right?  Virtually every tutorial on MVC 3 uses a blog as it's example.  There must be hundreds of them.  If you can't find an example of how to do a blog, i have to think you didn't even look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good tutorial from asp.net which should help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg702906

Hope this helps?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to develop powerful dynamic websites with patterns-based which enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over markup for enjoyable, agile development then MVC (Model view controller) is the best option in current software engineering cycle.

http://www.amarinfotech.com/services/mvc-architecture.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. The original poster specifically asks for tutorials on developing a blog using ASP MVC 3, not about which paradigm to develop with.